# After creating a Trigger via Callback in Room db, the trigger is not getting created

Tags: android, android-room

I tried to add a trigger to limit the number of rows in my Room DB,

but the trigger is not getting created- as I see in the DB and in the generated JSON file that automatically created.

Also, migration code is not getting reached as well.

My code for creating the DB is:

```
@Database(entities ={Sensor.class, Meter.class, MeterHistory.class, SensorHistory.class,
        ConnectivityHistory.class, GraphTypesHistory.class,
        SensorSettingsHistory.class, UserInterfaceSettings.class, Temperature.class, LogSettingsHistory.class, BatteryUsage.class,
        FunctionsHistory.class, MathChannelData.class}, version = 5)
@TypeConverters(UserUsageManager.DateConverter.class)
public abstract class UserUsageDB extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserUsageDao userUsageDao();
    private static volatile UserUsageDB userUsageDBInstance;//singleton

    static UserUsageDB getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (userUsageDBInstance == null) {
            synchronized (UserUsageDB.class) {
                if  (userUsageDBInstance == null) {
                    userUsageDBInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            UserUsageDB.class,  "user_usage_database")
                            .addCallback(LIMIT_CALLBACK)
                            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return userUsageDBInstance;
    }
```

and the code of the migration and trigger callback:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Create the new meters table
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE meters_new ( id TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))");
        // Copy the data
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO meters_new ( id, name) SELECT id, name FROM meters");
        // Remove the old table
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE meters");
        // Change the table name to the correct one
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE meters_new RENAME TO meters");

        // Create the new sensors table
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE sensors_new (id TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, type TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))");
        // Copy the data
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO sensors_new ( id, name) SELECT id, name FROM sensors");
        // Remove the old table
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE sensors");
        // Change the table name to the correct one
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE sensors_new RENAME TO sensors");
    }
};

//create a trigger to limit row count of tables
static final RoomDatabase.Callback LIMIT_CALLBACK =  new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        db.execSQL("Create Trigger IF NOT EXISTS Trigr_Limit_battery_usage_Delete \n" +
                "AFTER Insert On battery_usage \n" +
                "   BEGIN \n"+
                "       DELETE from battery_usage\n"+
                "       where ts in (select ts  from battery_usage order by date limit -1 offset 10);"+
                "   END");

        db.execSQL("Create Trigger IF NOT EXISTS Trigr_Limit_sensor_settings_history_Delete \n" +
                "AFTER Insert On sensor_settings_history \n" +
                "   BEGIN \n"+
                "       DELETE from sensor_settings_history\n"+
                "       where ts in (select ts  from sensor_settings_history order by date limit -1 offset 10);"+
                "   END");
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
    }
};
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the trigger is not getting created

You are Overriding the onCreate method, this only gets called when the database is actually created (first time the App is installed). You want to Override the  **onOpen** method to add the Triggers.

> migration code is not getting reached as well.

Migration is from version 1 to 2 as per (`new Migration(1, 2)`), you have version 5 coded in the App as per `version = 5` . Your migration will only be called when the version stored in the database is 1 and the version coded in the App is 2. You may find [Understanding migrations with Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929) useful. Or perhaps [Migrating Room databases](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#java)

Comment: T , I can't understand, I Override the OnOpen method, i need to override the OnCreate?

Comment: hi @Mike T, also about the migration, as I understand, in my DB I need a migration between 1 and 2 versions only, and for the other versions I added .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()- what means I don't care about migrations for thos versions only for the one that  I specified, is this correct?

Comment: @batsheva you only need to override the onCreate method if something needs to be done, such as inserting some initial data, when the database is created. The onOpen override will be actioned every time the database is built (fortunately you used IF NOT EXISTS so trying to create the triggers on every open doesn't fail). Re-migration, then if that's your requirement then yes it's correct **if you want the database to be cleared (i.e. lose all data)**. If you want to keep the data AND nothing is changed (why change the database version?) then provide a migration that does nothing.